# cocoa-applescript: Determinate progress indicator

Tags: xcode, cocoa, progress-bar, applescript-objc

I am making an application using Cocoa-Applescript which identifies local IP addresses which are up and running, by pinging x.y.z.[1-255] and appends running IPs to a text file. I already have a GUI for choosing x, y and z and have already made the script to ping each address:

```
repeat 255 times
         try
            do shell script "ping -o -t 1 -c 1 " & ipstamp & num4
            do shell script "echo " & ipstamp & num4 & " >>/Users/DJ/Desktop/GoodIPs.txt"
        end try
        set num4 to (num4 + 1)
    end repeat
```

Where ***ipstamp*** is x.y.z and ***num4*** is the [1-255]. But now I want a progress indicator to show where it is up to in the process. I know how to get an indeterminate indicator which simply starts and stops:

```
ProgressBar's startAnimation_(ProgressBar)
## code to ping IP address
ProgressBar's stopAnimation_(ProgressBar)
```

But that is only indeterminate and I can not find any info on setting *determinate* ones in Cocoa-Applescript, setting their maximum steps and setting their current step - much like in regular Applescript's:

```
set progress total steps to x
set progress completed steps to y
```

Except it is in the GUI, and so i need to use NSProgressIndicators to do it. So summed up, how do you make a *determinate* progress bar, how do you set its total steps and how do you update its current step?

### EDIT

It can be changed to determinate in the menu builder's Attribute Inspector, as can max, min and current steps. However I do need to be able to change the maximum and current steps from within the script, so those still apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can make a Determinate progress indercator but the problem is you have to repeat telling it to go to a certain lenght by using the

```
setDoubleValue_()
```

message, but anyway here is a simple script to tell it to go to go up to 100

```
property MyProgressBar : missing value -- Progress Bar IB Outlet

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    set c to 0
    repeat 100 times
        set c to c + 1
        delay 0.2
        tell MyProgressBar to setDoubleValue_(c) -- Tells Progress bar the % to go to
        if c > 99 then
            exit repeat -- If current repeat is 100 or more then cancels adding more
        end if
    end repeat
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
set progress total steps to -1
-- do something
set progress total steps to 0
```

Remember, that the visualization depends on how the script is executed.