# How to get a progress of NSAppleScript execution in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I tried to get an output of NSAppleScript execution in runtime, but I found the solution only where I can get the output **after** script's execution. I want to get output step by step like using NSTask with NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification notifications and waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify method.

I cannot use NSTask because I need a script execution with root privileges.

Maybe I can use default stdout with NSAppleScript for that purpose, but I don't know how.

Comment: You could use Cocoa Scripting to make your script vend and update an NSProgress object.

Comment: What do you mean by Cocoa Scripting? Can you show me an example of using that?

Comment: Perhaps you know it as AppleScriptObjC. The point is, you can use AppleScript to create an manage an Objective-C object, and now your Objective-C code can respond. For example: http://forum.latenightsw.com/t/applescriptobjc-nsprogress/300

Comment: Similarly here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010649/cocoa-applescript-determinate-progress-indicator

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thank you. I will research for that